# Get name of currently active thread in ThreadPoolExecutor android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

I have a threadpool executor defined as

[image]

Now as seen , there is one activeThread. How can i get its name, I want to compare it with debugger thread list, i can't find `pool-1-thread-2` anywhere but there is `pool-1-thread-1`.

Is that the active thread or how can i get the name of active thread to compare with list of all running threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `threadNumber` value is most likely incremented in anticipation of the next `Thread` to be named. Notice that the number of active threads and the pool size are both 1, meaning the pool has only doled out a single thread so far... which would be `pool-1-thread-1`.

In a more general notion, there is `getName()` in `Thread` and you can use a watch expression in the debugger or log output to see it. Also note there is `Thread.currentThread()` to get the current instance. If you want to get more complicated you can subclass the `Executor`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems that the thread is stuck at wait(). it hangs up when the threads call             response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
Is there any way i can manage it to interrupt/stop or do something about it. i am not sure why it even hangs on here

Comment: The execute call is waiting for a response and not getting one. There's either a problem with the request, a problem on the server side, or (maybe less likely) a connectivity issue. Or since you are calling from Android, there may be a permissions issue. I'd have to know more about the context and see log output to narrow it down. If you have a reference to the `Thread` you can call `interrupt()`, but that won't solve the underlying problem.